# HttpModule isn't processing request authentication

Tags: asp.net, http, httpmodule

I have an HttpHandler that I'm trying to use to put a little security layer over a certain directory in my site, but it's behaving strangely.

I've got it registered like this in my Web.Config: ***no longer valid since I'm in IIS 7.5***

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="/courses/*" type="CoursesAuthenticationHandler" />
```

I can't tell if it's actually being called or not, because regardless of the code, it always seems to do nothing. On the flip side, if there are any errors in the code, it does show me an error page until I've corrected the error.

Here's the handler itself:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class CoursesAuthenticationHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

So... that's pretty much it. The handler is being registered and analyzed at compile time, but doesn't actually do what it's expected to.

**Edit:** I realized that I'm using IIS 7.5 and that does indeed have an impact on this implementation.

For IIS 7, here's the Web.Config registration I used:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script"> 
  <add name="CoursesAuthenticationHandler" 
    verb="*" 
    path="/courses/*" 
    type="CoursesAuthenticationHandler" 
    resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

**Edit 2:** Progress! When not logged in, requests made to the `/courses/` directory are redirected to the login page. However, authenticated requests to the `/courses/` directory return empty pages...

**Edit 3:** Per @PatrickHofman's suggestion, I've switched to using an `HttpModule`.

The Web.Config registration:

```
<modules>     
    <add name="CourseAuthenticationModule" type="CourseAuthenticationModule" />
```

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class CourseAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginRequest);
    }

    public void BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = app.Context;
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        if (request.Path.ToLower().StartsWith("/courses/") && !request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            response.Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

*Now* the problem is that `!request.IsAuthenticated` is *always* false. If I'm logged in, and navigate to the `/courses/` directory, I'm redirected to the homepage.

What's the deal?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using. Can you also show 1 or 2 levels up in your web.config?

Comment: I'm using IIS 7. I actually just realized that that matters, so I'm about to update the question.

Comment: Checking you are using system.webserver instead of system.web.

Comment: aha - are you running in integrated pipeline mode, or classic mode?

Comment: I am in `system.webServer`, @PatrickHofman.

Comment: Integrated. @RobLevine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the last problem lies in the fact that a `HttpHander` handles stuff. It is the end point of a request.

Since you didn't add anything to the request, the response will end up empty.

Are you looking for `HttpModule`s? They can be stacked.

As a possible solution when only files are necessary: read the files yourself in the request by either reading and writing to response or use `TransmitFile`. For ASP.NET pages you need modules.

Comment: I actually tried HttpModules, but I ran into issues with redirect loops and requests never being authenticated. All I need my handler to do at this point is respond with the requested resources...

Comment: Snap. Turns out that modules might be the way to go. If I can get one working, I'll accept this as the answer. What a shame.

Comment: Check the updated question. I swear I'm so close to getting this working, it's just behaving so strangely... @PatrickHofman

Comment: @kehrk: Try to handle the request later, probably with the `HttpApplication.PostAuthenticateRequest` event. I think it hasn't authenticated yet.

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks a *ton*.